# Magento change shipping price when create order

Tags: magento

I'm create order programmaticaly, and all works fine. But i need to change shipping price. I try to:

```
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
->setShippingAmount('200')
->setBaseShippingAmount('200')
->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
```

But in admin it still shows Shipping & Handling InformationFlat Rate - Fixed €12,230.00

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the shipping price for all your orders, best way to do it is to change the config on the admin panel: System->Configuration->Shipping Method->Flat Rate, the Price field.

If this is something you need for different orders, the best way to do it is to create custom shipping methods. You can see [Magento's guideline to do so](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module), or [this other article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/) which is also nice.